# why is OpenMP messing this for loop?

Tags: c, multithreading, audio, openmp

I'm trying to use OpenMP in my audio code.
I'm using Miniaudio as audio backend, a pretty handy single-header multi-platform library, you can find it [here](https://github.com/mackron/miniaudio/blob/master/miniaudio.h).

Here is my code, I tried to distill it to its minimum working form:

```c
/*** DEFINES */
    #define MA_NO_DECODING
    #define MA_NO_ENCODING
    #define MINIAUDIO_IMPLEMENTATION

    #define WAVES_QTY 1000
    #define FREQ_INIT 50.f
    #define FREQ_STEP 1.f

    #define DEVICE_FORMAT ma_format_f32
    #define DEVICE_CHANNELS 1
    #define DEVICE_SAMPLE_RATE 8000
/* DEFINES end. */

/*** INCLUDES */
    /* single header library from https://github.com/mackron/miniaudio/blob/master/miniaudio.h */
    #include "miniaudio.h"

    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdint.h>
    #include <math.h>
    #include <omp.h>
/* INCLUDES end. */

/*** GLOBALS */
    float phaseArray[WAVES_QTY];
    float amplitudeArray[WAVES_QTY];
    float freqArray[WAVES_QTY];
/* GLOBALS end. */

/*** FUNCTION DECLARATIONS */
    void data_callback(ma_device* pDevice, void* pOutput, const void* pInput, ma_uint32 frameCount);
/* FUNCTION DECLARATIONS end. */    

/*** MAIN */
    int main(){
        uint32_t i;
        ma_device_config deviceConfig;
        ma_device device;

        printf("== will now initialize arrays...");
        for(i=0;i<WAVES_QTY;i++){
            phaseArray[i] = 0.f;
            amplitudeArray[i] = 1.f;
            freqArray[i] = FREQ_INIT + i*FREQ_STEP;
            amplitudeArray[i] /=  ((float)WAVES_QTY);/* so we don't overflow max volume */
        }
        printf(" DONE!\n");

        deviceConfig = ma_device_config_init(ma_device_type_playback);
        deviceConfig.playback.format   = DEVICE_FORMAT;
        deviceConfig.playback.channels = DEVICE_CHANNELS;
        deviceConfig.sampleRate        = DEVICE_SAMPLE_RATE;
        deviceConfig.dataCallback      = data_callback;
        if(ma_device_init(NULL, &deviceConfig, &device) != MA_SUCCESS){
            printf("Failed to open playback device.\n");
            return -4;
        }

        printf("== Device Name: %s\n", device.playback.name);

        /* this is the actual sound start */
        if (ma_device_start(&device) != MA_SUCCESS) {
            printf("== Failed to start playback device.\n");
            ma_device_uninit(&device);
            return -5;
        }

        printf("~~~ You should hear sound now ~~~\n");
        printf("== Press Enter to quit...");
        getchar();

        ma_device_uninit(&device); /* clean up */

        return 0;
    }
/* MAIN end. */

/*** FUNCTION DEFINITIONS */
    void data_callback(ma_device* pDevice, void* pOutput, const void* pInput, ma_uint32 frameCount){
        float* Samples = pOutput;
        ma_uint32 SampleIndex;

        for(SampleIndex = 0; SampleIndex < frameCount; SampleIndex++){
            uint32_t ii;
            *Samples = 0.f;

            /**** HERE */
            #pragma omp parallel for private(ii) shared(phaseArray, freqArray, amplitudeArray, Samples)
            for(ii=0;  ii<WAVES_QTY; ii++){
                phaseArray[ii] = fmod(phaseArray[ii] + (freqArray[ii] / (float)(DEVICE_SAMPLE_RATE)), 1.f);
                *Samples += (float)sin((double)(phaseArray[ii] * (float)MA_TAU)) * amplitudeArray[ii];
            }

            Samples++;
        }
        (void)pDevice;
        (void)pInput;
    }
/* FUNCTION DEFINITIONS end. */
```

compiling on Win10, MinGW32 with
`gcc -g0 thousandwaves.c -fopenmp -o thousandwaves.exe -Wall -Wextra -Wshadow -Werror=implicit-int -Werror=incompatible-pointer-types -Werror=int-conversion -Wvla -pedantic-errors -ansi`

The program is quite simple, it generates 1000 sinewaves and mixes them together in real-time.
I'd like to run the sinewave generation on all available threads using OpenMP, so I added the `#pragma omp parallel for` in my `data_callback` function (I also marked the exact spot with the comment `/**** HERE */`).
It compiles and runs without errors/warnings, but the program generates a very noisy sound, vaguely resembling the original.(just comment/delete the #pragma to hear how it should sound).

I guess it has something to do with the nested for loops, but I can't pinpoint the problem. I'm targeting only the inner loop with my #pragma, so it should parallelize only that section.

Let me know what do you think, thanks :))

EDIT:
thanks a lot all, the `reduction` clause does the trick indeed, and also, using `atomic` inside the loop further speeds up things

```c
    void data_callback(ma_device* pDevice, void* pOutput, const void* pInput, ma_uint32 frameCount){
        float* Samples = pOutput;
        ma_uint32 SampleIndex;

        for(SampleIndex = 0; SampleIndex < frameCount; SampleIndex++){
            uint32_t ii;
            float sample = 0.f;

            #pragma omp parallel for private(ii) shared(phaseArray, freqArray, amplitudeArray, Samples) reduction(+:sample)
            for(ii=0;  ii<WAVES_QTY; ii++){
                phaseArray[ii] = fmod(phaseArray[ii] + (freqArray[ii] / (float)(DEVICE_SAMPLE_RATE)), 1.f);
                #pragma omp atomic update
                sample += (float)sin((double)(phaseArray[ii] * (float)MA_TAU)) * amplitudeArray[ii];
                
            }

            *Samples = sample;
            Samples++;
        }
        (void)pDevice;
        (void)pInput;
    }
```

Comment: Regarding the number of instruction, using multiple threads may not be significantly faster (or at least it should not scale well). An alternative solution is to vectorize the code, especially since you use 32-bit floating-point numbers (4 items can fit in a SSE register and 8 in an AVX register). Micro optimizations can also help (for example a sin approximation) as well as using fast-math. The `fmod` and `sin` function of the libmath are certainly inefficient (at least for the default GCC and Clang implementation).

Comment: mackron..., that's a very good repo name.

Comment: @Jérôme Richard absolutely! In my original code I'm using a fast_sin function, I'll have a look for a faster fmod as well, thanks for the heads-up. Also -Ofast, how could I have forgotten? Thanks! Will also read more about omp simd for vectorization

Answer (score 2, accepted):

all threads are writing to `*Samples`, this is a race condition which should be atomic, and would result in slower code than serial code.

```cpp
#pragma omp atomic
*Samples += (float)sin((double)(phaseArray[ii] * (float)MA_TAU)) * amplitudeArray[ii];
```

Edit: as pointed by @Jérôme a reduction will be faster

```c
void data_callback(ma_device* pDevice, void* pOutput, const void* pInput, ma_uint32 frameCount) {
    float* Samples = pOutput;
    ma_uint32 SampleIndex;

    for (SampleIndex = 0; SampleIndex < frameCount; SampleIndex++) {
        int32_t ii;
        *Samples = 0.f;
        float sample = 0.f;

        /**** HERE */
        #pragma omp parallel for private(ii) shared(phaseArray, freqArray, amplitudeArray) reduction(+:sample)
        for (ii = 0; ii < WAVES_QTY; ii++) {
            phaseArray[ii] = fmod(phaseArray[ii] + (freqArray[ii] / (float)(DEVICE_SAMPLE_RATE)), 1.f);
            sample += (float)sin((double)(phaseArray[ii] * (float)MA_TAU)) * amplitudeArray[ii];
        }
        *Samples = sample;
        Samples++;
    }
    (void)pDevice;
    (void)pInput;
}
```

Comment: A reduction would be more efficient in this case, especially since the amount of work is small. The [code generated by GCC](https://godbolt.org/z/MPTd3qKP9) uses a `lock cmpxchg` instruction, that is a compare and swap loop which is inefficient (not to mention a jump to an indirect temporary block). It may take a significant time compared to the rest of the loop and does not scale on many cores. [Clang does the same thing](https://godbolt.org/z/Wx4scz9PM).

Comment: thanks a lot, this works like a charm!
Curiously, adding an atomic pragma on top of the reduction seems to make it even faster. I can notice it when compiling without fast-math, as there are fewer high frequency clicks, meaning the buffer gets filled on time more often
Will edit my OP to show that

Comment: @nff this depends on the number of cores and data size, the reduction is the most scalable as in for very large data and large number of cores it will be best, but for small data or small number of cores it's likely that threading itself won't be faster than a serial code.